# Make a DIV show with jQuery in nested accordion structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an accordion that is loaded from a model list, so it is repeated with new IDs assigned according to the ID of the model.  In this structure I have a DIV is display:none and upon clicking a radio button I want it to slide down and show.  This is some of my HTML:

```
<tr style="height:35px">
    <td style="text-align:left" >
        <label id="lblOtherAvery+@Model[i].UserId" style="font-size:x-small">Other:</label> 
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x=>Model[i].AverySize, "Other", new { @id = "chkOtherAvery" + @Model[i].UserId, @style = "width:30px;", @class = "radLabel radLabelOther", @disabled = "disabled"})
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:center" colspan="2" >
        <div id="divAvery_@Model[i].UserId" style="display:none;vertical-align:top;text-align:center" class="divAvery">
            <table style="width:100%;text-align:center">
                <tr style="height:20px;">
                    <td style="font-size:x-small">Rows:</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>Model[i].LabelRows, new {@id = "txtRows" + @Model[i].Userd, style = "width:50px;font-size:x-small;height:20px"})<span style="font-size:x-small"><i>(MAX 16)</i></span></td>
                    <td style="font-size:x-small">Columns:</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>Model[i].LabelColumns, new {@id = "txtColumns" + @Model[i].UserId, style = "width:50px;font-size:x-small;height:20px"})<span style="font-size:x-small"><i>(MAX 3)</i></span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then in the JS for when the radio is clicked:

```
$('.radLabelOther').on('click', function () {
    var divId = $(this).closest('tr').next().children().find('.divAvery');
    $(divid).slideDown().show();
});
```

But this doesn't work.  I am able to get the DIV element OK, but I cannot get it to show.  What am I doing wrong?

I have even tried to get the ID of the DIV with this:

```
 var divId = $(this).closest('tr').next().children().find('.divAvery').attr('id');
```

But that doesn't work either.

I can get it to work now by doing this:

```
 var $divId = $(this).closest('tr').next().children().find('.divAvery');
 $divId.slideDown();
```

Why does that $ make it work?

Comment: Any special reason you use `slideDown` and `show` together?

Comment: No, but it doesn't work with either alone or together.

Comment: Your `div` has an `id ` that must be unique. Why you don't use that? `$("#yourId").show();`

Comment: @AlexChar I can get the ID, as I have indicated.  It comes back like "divAvery_123456789" but that doesn't work.  I have even tried adding the pound sign to the beginning of the ID and that doesn't work either.

Comment: You get any errors in console?